# how to change text angle for labels in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I want to change text axis of the labels so that they wont be overlapped when there is large number of labels. Fiddle is given below to see code
http://fiddle.jshell.net/fdzbv6vg/16/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://fiddle.jshell.net/4rsLghb7/

Line 59 Change :

```
 return "translate(`enter code here`" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
```

To this

```
        return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")rotate(" + angle(d) + ")";
```

Comment: can you just tell me how to make that chart responsive? on window zoom it is getting larger and going out of window

Comment: can you help me with one more thing which i asked above in comments

Comment: @Tejas that's another question :) i don't have quick answer for it